# Does my "zipLatest" operator already exist?

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs

quick question about an operator I've written for myself.

Please excuse my poor-man's marble diagrams:

```
zip
aa--bb--cc--dd--ee--ff--------gg
--11----22--33--------44--55----
================================
--a1----b2--c3--------d4--e5----

combineLatest
aa--bb--cc--dd--ee--ff--------gg
--11----22--33--------44--55----
================================
--a1b1--c2--d3--e3--f3f4--f5--g5

zipLatest
aa--bb--cc--dd--ee--ff--------gg
--11----22--33--------44--55----
================================
--a1----c2--d3--------f4------g5
```

`zipLatest` (the one I wrote) fires at almost the same times as `zip`, but without the queueing `zip` includes.

I've already implemented it, I'm just wondering if this already exists.
I know I wrote a similar method in the past, to discover by random chance that I'd written the `sample` operator without knowing it.

So, does this already exist in the framework, or exist as a trivial composition of elements I haven't thought of?

Note: I don't want to rely on equality of my inputs to deduplicate (a la `distinctUntilChanged`).
It should work with a signal that only outputs `"a"` on an interval.

Comment: There is an implementation of `ZipLatest` in UniRx - https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx

Comment: To assure you, I dont believe there is an implementation of this in Rx. The marbles diagrams are great btw.

Comment: @Enigmativity hey so there is. It even appears, at first glance, to do the same thing. Guess I picked an ok name.

Comment: @psycotica0: This looks similar to [withLatestFrom](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) which is present rxjs. Just wondering if f5 should be emitted or not?

Comment: Looks similar to [`zipLatest()`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowablesziplatest) for RxJava.

Answer (score 2):

To give an update on the issue: There is still no operator for this requirement included in RxJS 6 and none seems to be planned for future releases. There are also no open pull requests that propose this operator.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602541/rxjs-lossy-form-of-zip-operator), a combination of `combineLatest`, `first` and `repeat` will produce the expected behaviour:

```
combineLatest(obs1, obs2).pipe(first()).pipe(repeat());
```

`combineLatest` will wait for the emission of both Observables - throwing away all emissions apart from the latest of each. `first` will complete the Observable after the emission and `repeat` resubscribes on `combineLatest`, causing it to wait again for the latest values of both observables.

The resubscription behaviour of `repeat` is not fully documented, but can be found in the [GitHub source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/01a09789a0a9484c368b7bd6ed37f94d25490a00/src/internal/operators/repeat.ts):

> source.subscribe(this._unsubscribeAndRecycle());

Answer (score 0):

Though you specifically mentions not to use DistinctUntilChanged, you can use it with a counter to distinct new values:

```
public static IObservable<(T, TSecond)> ZipLatest<T, TSecond>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<TSecond> second)
{
    return source.Select((value, id) => (value, id))
        .CombineLatest(second.Select((value, id) => (value, id)), ValueTuple.Create)
        .DistinctUntilChanged(x => (x.Item1.id, x.Item2.id), new AnyEqualityComparer<int, int>())
        .Select(x => (x.Item1.value, x.Item2.value));
}

public class AnyEqualityComparer<T1, T2> : IEqualityComparer<(T1 a, T2 b)>
{
    public bool Equals((T1 a, T2 b) x, (T1 a, T2 b) y) => Equals(x.a, y.a) || Equals(x.b, y.b);
    public int GetHashCode((T1 a, T2 b) obj) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Note that I've used Int32 here - because that's what Select() gives me - but it might be to small for some use cases. Int64 or Guid might be a better choice.