# Kind of withLatestFrom both variable speed sources

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have following case with result i want to achieve:

```
L --1---3---4---5---6---7---8-
R ---A--------B--CDE-FG--H---I

O ---A--------B--C--E---G---H-
  ---1--------4--5--6---7---H-
```

So basically I have two sources with relative speed changing over time. The result should ignore Sometimes `L` elements and sometimes `R` elements. How to build that kind of RX?

I was trying with Joins, Sample, WithLatestFrom, Distincts etc. But I can always ignore some elements from `L` source but not `R`. 
I am trying to achieve it in C# but any language answer will be helpful.

Comment: Why does `H7` get output and not `G7`?

Comment: True, mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking for a `ZipLatest` implementation. See [Does my "zipLatest" operator already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190722/does-my-ziplatest-operator-already-exist)

**EDIT**:

If you want an implementation, without downloading a library, I think this would work:

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<T1, T2>> ZipLatest<T1, T2>(this IObservable<T1> left, IObservable<T2> right)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var leftSubject = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
        var rightSubject = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);

        return left.Publish(_left =>
            right.Publish(_right =>
            {
                return Observable.CombineLatest(
                    _left,
                    _right,
                    _left.Select(_ => true).Merge(leftSubject),
                    _right.Select(_ => true).Merge(rightSubject), 
                    (l, r, l_bool, r_bool) => Tuple.Create(l_bool, r_bool, l, r)
                )
                    .Where(t => t.Item1 && t.Item2)
                    .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item3, t.Item4))
                    .Do(_ =>
                    {
                        leftSubject.OnNext(false);
                        rightSubject.OnNext(false);
                    });
            })
        );
    });
```

Running it against @Enigmativity's test code (modified)...

```
void Main()
{
    var L = new Subject<int>();
    var R = new Subject<char>();

    var O = L.ZipLatest(R)
        .Select(t => new { l = t.Item1, r = t.Item2});

    O.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine($"{o.l}{o.r}"));

    L.OnNext(1);
    R.OnNext('A');
    L.OnNext(3);
    L.OnNext(4);
    R.OnNext('B');
    L.OnNext(5);
    R.OnNext('C');
    R.OnNext('D');
    R.OnNext('E');
    L.OnNext(6);
    R.OnNext('F');
    R.OnNext('G');
    L.OnNext(7);
    R.OnNext('H');
    L.OnNext(8);
    R.OnNext('I');
}
```

...you get the correct results:

```
1A
4B
5C
6E
7G
8H
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt for now; I will try this in a compiler later!

Keep track of the last value sent through a combine latest and ensure that each value is unique before applying the operation. Define this operation as an extension method.

```
public static IObservable<C> ZipLatest<A, B, C>(
    this IObservable<A> sourceA,
    IObservable<B> sourceB,
    Func<A, B, C> op) 
{
    IObservable<Tuple<A, B>> combined = sourceA.CombineLatest(
            sourceB, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b));
    Tuple<A, B> last = null;
    return combined.Where(curr => 
    {
        if (last == null || (last.Item1 != curr.Item1 && last.Item2 != curr.Item2))
        {
            last = curr;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).Select(curr => op(curr.Item1, curr.Item2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a rule in what you're asking for. You need to be able to consistently describe what should happen with values from `L` and `R`.

This is the closest that I could get:

```
var L = new Subject<int>();
var R = new Subject<char>();

var O = L.Select(l => R.Select(r => new { r, l })).Switch();

O.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine($"{o.l}{o.r}"));

L.OnNext(1);
R.OnNext('A');
L.OnNext(3);
L.OnNext(4);
R.OnNext('B');
L.OnNext(5);
R.OnNext('C');
R.OnNext('D');
R.OnNext('E');
L.OnNext(6);
R.OnNext('F');
R.OnNext('G');
L.OnNext(7);
R.OnNext('H');
L.OnNext(8);
R.OnNext('I');
```

That gave me:

```
1A
4B
5C
5D
5E
6F
6G
7H
8I
```

Also, from your marble diagram it's not clear if `'F'` or `6` comes first. You need to clarify the value order and the rules to combine the streams.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I corrected the diagram. Similar results to yours I achieved using Join or CombineLatest. The key problem here is both sources have to follow same rule: "I can notify only once per other source interval between elements". Plus no element from both sources can appear in result twice.